# Base64encoding and base64decoding in dart and Java

Tags: java, dart, encoding, base64, decoding

Is base64encode and decode in dart is same for Java. In my flutter app I want to upload an image. I convert that image to string by base64Encode(file. readAsBytesSync()). And then I passed it to backend. Backendcode is in JAVA. I want to decode this image file in java for save into a folder. How it is possible. Is I decode image gives same result.? I want to fetch it back also. Please help

Comment: Get [decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html#getDecoder()) then [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#decode(java.lang.String)) into bytes then [read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) back as image using [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

Comment: Thanku.. Is it give same image result? Is there any issue occur

Comment: Finaly [write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File)) image to disk ImageIO.write(image,"png",new File("Your Location"))

Comment: Base 64 is universal everywhere so it should give the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting all my comments as an answer here are 2 utility functions

```
public static BufferedImage decode(String base64Image)throws Exception 
{
  Base64.Decoder decoder=Base64.getDecoder();

  ByteArrayInputStream decoded=new ByteArrayInputStream(decoder.decode(base64Image));

  return ImageIO.read(decoded);
}

public static void writeImage(ByfferedImage img,File file)throws Exception 
{
 ImageIO.write(img,"png",file);
}
```